# Add new activity in eclipse android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, menu

I started programming for android with Eclipse a few days ago However, I am stuck now.

I would like to add a new activity, so that i can add a new screen with new layout (an info screen about the app)

It is made so that when you press a specific menu button (help) it launches the `help.xml` activity and shows a new screen with some new words.

This succeeded one time, but I cant manage to do this another time.

It just gives me the standard white themed screen.

Here is the code to direct to the activity, made from the `main.java`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate (R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.help:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, help.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.quit:
        finish();  
        break;
    }
}
```

I dont have code in the `help.java`, and I have made some buttons in `help.xml`

The 'quit' button works fine but the 'help' thing doesnt. I am also very unsure where it links to, as the previous time I had to both make a `help.java` and a `help.xml` activity.

I already noted the help activity in the `manifest.xml`

Comment: Show the code in `help.xml`

Answer (score 1):

You have to `@Override` the `onCreate()` in `Help` `Activity`.

See the following code:

```
public class Help extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate();
        setContentView(R.layout.help);
    }
}
```

Comment: What oncreate() do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I already did that, I thought it wasnt part of the important code for this.                                                            When clicking the help button i just get the standard themed white screen, do you know how to fix it so that i can use the help.xml layout?

Comment: is the `Help` activity listed in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Yes it is, as i said in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create `Help.java` and sent the contentView in `onCreate` to `R.layout.help`.

```
public class Help extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.help);
     }

 }
```

You then need to create an activity node in `AndroidManifest.xml` that points to Help.java.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

help.xml is not an Activity, I think this is your layout file for the Activity. You must create a new class which extends Activity:

```
public class help extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.help);
    }
}
```

If your Activity's name is "main" (as you described) where you start the new Activity, then you should change the Intent to this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(main.this, help.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I made a class named help.java, is that the correct one and do i have to put the code in there?

Comment: See the edit above. You have to put this code in help.java, because you must create the activity first with onCreate overriding.